# Scroll bar greyed out in tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to add a scroll bar into my tkinter application. It is appearing, however it is greyed out and is not able to scroll and I am not sure why despite the fact that I have many widgets beyond the height of the page. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')


x = 30
y = 30
box_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='apple.png')



### SCROLL BAR ###

# create a main frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

# create a canvas
my_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)

# add a scrollbar to the canvas
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient='vertical', command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

# configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

# create Another frame inside the canvas
second_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas)

# add that new frame to a window in the canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

def display():
    global x , y
    panel2 = tk.Label(main_frame, image=box_image, bg='#f7f6f6')
    panel2.place(x=x, y=y) 
    x = x
    y = y+200


button = tk.Button(main_frame, text="click me", command=display)
button.place(x=0, y=0)

for thing in range (100):
    tk.Button(main_frame, text=f'Button {thing}Yo!').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` on `second_frame` instead of `my_canvas`.

Comment: I think you need to create those buttons in `second_frame` instead of `main_frame`.

Answer (score 0):

For the frame-in-a-canvas trick to work, you must add the buttons to the inner frame:

```
for thing in range (100):
    tk.Button(second_frame, text=f'Button {thing}Yo!').pack()
    #         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: How would I make the `second_frame` wider? Because it seems that the width of the second frame is only as wide as the buttons and anything else that is placed in the second frame gets cut off.

Comment: @Minbutt: there are several ways. One way is to set the width when calling `create_window`.